# boost::regex - \bb?

Tags: c++, regex, perl, boost

I have some badly commented legacy code here that makes use of `boost::regex::perl`. I was wondering about one particular construct before, but since the code worked (more or less), I was loath to touch it.

Now I *have* to touch it, for technical reasons (more precisely, current versions of Boost no longer accepting the construct), so I have to figure out what it *does* - or rather, was *intended* to do.

The relevant part of the regex:

```
(?<!(\bb\s|\bb|^[a-z]\s|^[a-z]))
```

The piece that gives me headaches is `\bb`. I know of `\b`, but I could not find mention of `\bb`, and looking for a literal `'b'` would not make sense here. Is `\bb` some special underdocumented feature, or do I have to consider this a typo?

Comment: Could you not simply try if `\bb` matches "b" (and not "a") to check if it actually does anything other than word-boundary, followed by "b"?

Comment: Well, the problem - as with all uncommented code - is that what it *does* might not actually correlate with what it was *intended* to do. I'd have to test it against the old (1.34.1) and current Boost version, and *still* would have to guess about the intention of the author...

Comment: Read the source, Luke

(of boost::regex::perl that is.. good luck:)

Comment: If `\bb` had special meaning, then how would you specify a word-boundary followed by a `b`?

Comment: @mobrule: Well... d'oh. Excellent point. :-D

Comment: @mobrule: Turn it into an answer and you'll get the "correct" tag for the sheer simplistic beauty of it. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(\bb\s|\bb|^[a-z]\s|^[a-z])` matches a `b` if it's not preceded by another word character, or *any* lowercase letter if it's at the beginning of the string.  In either case, the letter may be followed by a whitespace character.  (It could match uppercase letters too if case-insensitive mode is set, and the `^` could also match the beginning of a line if multiline mode is set.)

But inside a lookbehind, that shouldn't even have *compiled*.  In some flavors, a lookbehind can contain multiple alternatives with different, fixed lengths, but the alternation has to be at the top level in the lookbehind.  That is, `(?<=abc|xy|12345)` will work, but `(?<=(abc|xy|12345))` won't.  So your regex wouldn't work even in *those* flavors, but Boost's docs just say the lookbehind expression has to be fixed-length.

If you really need to account for all four of the possibilities matched by that regex, I suggest you split the lookbehind into two:

```
(?<!\bb|^[a-z])(?<!(?:\bb|^[a-z])\s)
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that "alternation has to be at the top level in the lookbehind".

Answer (score 4):

As [Boost](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/boost/libs/regex/doc/introduction.html) seems to be a regex engine for C++, and *one* of the compatibility modes is perl compatibility--if that is a "perl-compatible" expression, than the second 'b' can *only* be a literal.

It's a valid expression, pretty much a special case for words beginning with 'b'.

It seems to be the deciding factor that this is a c++ library, and that it's to give environments that *aren't* perl, perl-compatible regexes. Thus my original thought that perl might interpret the expression (say with [`overload::constant`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload#Overloading_constants)) is invalid. Yet it is still worth mentioning just for clarification purposes, regardless of how inadvisable it would be tweak an expression meaning "word beginning with 'b'".

The only caveat to that idea is that *perhaps* Boost out-performs Perl at it's own expressions and somebody would be using the Boost engine *in* a Perl environment, then all bets are off as to whether that could have been meant as a special expression. This is just one stab, given a grammar where '!!!' meant something special at the beginning of words, you could piggyback on the established meaning like this (NOT RECOMMENDED!)

```
s/\\bb\b/(?:!!!(\\p{Alpha})|\\bb)/
```

This would be something dumb to do, but as we are dealing with code that seems unfit for its task, there are thousands of ways to fail at a task.